# Range filter not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the elasticsearch search engine and when I run the code below, the results returned doesn't match the range criteria(I get items with published date below the desired limit):

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/newsidx/news/_search?pretty' -d '{

    "fields": [
        "art_text",
        "title",
        "published",
        "category"
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {

            "should": [
                {
                    "fuzzy": {"art_text": {"boost": 89, "value": "google" }}
                },
                {
                    "fuzzy": {"art_text": {"boost": 75, "value": "twitter" }}
                }
            ],
            "minimum_number_should_match": 1
        }
    },
    "filter" : {
        "range" : {
            "published" : {
                "from" : "2013-04-12 00:00:00"
            }
        }
    }

}

'
```

I also tried putting the range clause in a must one, inside the bool query, but the results were the same.

Edit: I use elasticsearch to search in a mongodb through a river plugin. This is the script I ran to search the mongodb db with ES:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta -d '{
        "type":"mongodb",
        "mongodb": {
                "db": "newsful",
                "collection": "news"
        },
    "index": {
            "name": "newsidx",
        "type": "news"
    }
}'
```

Besides this, I didn't create another indexes.

Edit 2:

A view to the es mappings:

```
http://localhost:9200/newsidx/news/_mapping

published: {
    type: "string"
}
```

Comment: is your `published` field indexed as a date? Can you post your current mapping please?

Comment: I edited the post in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is in your mapping. The published field, which you are using as a date, is indexed as a string. That's probably because the [date format](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/date-format/) you are using is not the default one in elasticsearch, thus the field type is not auto-detected and it's indexed as a simple string.

You should change your mapping using the [put mapping api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/). You need to define the published field as a date there, specifying the format you're using (can be more than one) and reindex your data.

After that your range filter should work!